# Making the redirect URL in my code with qrytype parameter from HTML extracted from GMAIL Body using GMAIL API

Tags: c#, encoding, base64, gmail-api, urlencode

Guys I am trying to extract link from gmail body from the link tag but there is also an extra querytype parameter. And the link I am extracting is showing invalid. I researched online and to my surprise google does this redirect thing and to store data(Google being Google). So my question is how do I make the complete url with this querytype param??
HTML ->

```
Click Here
<https://scdelivery.kfintech.com/c/?u=undefined&p=qqttqbdb.bqeesknn--241356680-4ECA083E-630F-4204-893C-AAE2371635DA.1.1&e=s1
qrytype=TXxXQkNVTTEwMzg1MzE5MTE1MzExfDIwMjMwODI1>  to download the
report.
```

I tried decoding this qrytype from Base64 but I am getting only file name which is supposedly to be downloaded when clicking the complete link.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].